# Is ‘understand’ a noun in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> Now the teacher plays the tapes or reads the text again, pausing after every sentence to check the students understand.

Is *‘understand’* a noun in the sentence above?

Comment: Are you sure you meant "understand", not "understanding"/

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a noun.

The normal wording of that sentence would be, "... pausing after every sentence to check **that** the students understand." Sometimes people leave out the word "that" from dependent clauses like this.

For example:

> "The teacher knew **that** her students understood the assignment."

is equivalent to

> "The teacher knew her students understood the assignment."

In the particular case quoted in your question, I don't think it sounds exactly proper, although it's probably acceptable. But even without the word "that", "understand" is still a verb with "students" as its subject.

Comment: ...pausing after every sentence to check that the students understand.   Why not use ‘if’ instead of ‘that’ here?

Comment: @Y. zeng , yes, I didn't think of it, but "... pausing after every sentence to check **if** the students understand." probably sounds slightly better.

Comment: So, that is to say if can be omitted in the sentence I wrote first. But I have never seen any sentence that omitted ‘if’ before.

Comment: Why is ‘if’ the same as ‘whether’?

Comment: @Y.zeng If you use "if" instead of "that", you change the grammar and the meaning. In the latter case, "that" is omissible, but in interrogatives with "if" it is not.

Comment: @Y.zeng The point is that "that" is a subordinator that introduces declarative content clauses like "(that) the students understand" where it is sometimes omissible, as here. But "if the students understand" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question. That is the difference..

Comment: @ Y.zeng ,"If" very often substitutes for "whether" in the everyday speech of lots of native speakers, even though they aren't really synonyms. "Whether" is really the word that is best here, but I don't think anyone would omit the word "whether."

Answer (score 1):

The word “understand” is a verb, referring to the action of comprehending. As such, the sentence as is is incorrect. However, it can be easily rectified by adding the letters “ing” to the end. The word “understanding” in this context would indeed be a noun, referring to the state of the students’ comprehension.

Comment: Yes: it could be a typo where the intended word is the noun "understanding". But as written by the OP, "(that) the students understand" is a declarative content clause where "that" is omissible.